How to use Face ID in PWA and integrate with Azure AD B2C
We have implemented an Azure backend that exposes a Web API and uses Azure AD B2C to authenticate users. These APIs are consumed by a web portal that is built using a low code platform. When a user navigates to the web portal he is first redirected to Azure AD B2C to login with username/password plus MFA. Upon successful login the user receives a JWT token which is passed in an authorization header to API calls. The API verifies the token and returns data to the portal. A token is valid for one hour and once expired the user has to login again with username/password and MFA.

We are now investigating if we can make the portal available as PWA. The main idea behind this is that we can offer the user an app and use Face ID (or an alternative depending on OS) to make the login process more convenient. The scenario we have in mind is that the user needs to login only the first time with username/password + MFA, and then enable Face ID (or alternative depending on OS) for future logins. So for future logins the user no longer needs to enter username/password + MFA, but this replaced by Face ID.
I am trying to get my head around how integration with Face ID could work in relation to Azure AD B2C. Our backend APIs only work with an Azure AD B2C token, so I expect the PWA still needs to request a token from Azure AD B2C, but what is the role of Face ID in this flow? Do we need to create a separate custom policy in Azure AD B2C in which we can somehow verify Face ID?
Has anyone experience with such flow? Any help or pointers to relevant documentation or diagrams are highly appreciated.
UPDATE:
Based on the feedback by rbrayb we looked further and stumbled upon this explainer video on Web Authentication and Face ID and Touch ID for the web. Our current idea is to persist the public key credential returned by the Web Authentication API as a custom attribute in Azure AD B2C. At the time we offer the user the option to enable Face ID he is logged in, so we know exactly on which user the public key credential should be persist and we can use the Graph API to do this.
The next time the user needs to login the portal should detect that Face ID is available and provide Face ID login. Once the user successfully passed Face ID validation, we redirect to a different custom policy in Azure AD B2C. This policy invokes an API in our backend that again uses the Graph API to query for a user with a matching public key credential. When found, a token is issued.
Does this flow make sense? Are we missing some crucial parts here?


Typically, you would use a 3rd party to provide this.
This 3rd party would be an external OIDC IDP to B2C.
You could also use Entra Verified ID.
Samples here.

Thanks, I looked into these examples and if I understand it correctly these solutions replace the current MFA step (mail or sms) with an app that handles biometrics. I am actually looking for something more integrated into the OS like Face ID. Your answer helped me to guide me to more relevant search criteria and solutions. I have updated the original question with an idea how the flow could work with Web Authentication.
